# Relacionar tabelas para fazer recomendações ao cliente?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Tenho uma tabela "curtidos", "comentados" e "visitados", cada vez que um usuário curte, comenta ou visita um determinado livro em minha página um registro é inserido no banco de dados referente a tal:

Tabela curtidos:

```
+----------------+-------------+
| id_livro       | usuario     |
+----------------+-------------+
|     1          | user_id     |
+----------------+-------------+
|     4          | user_id     |
+----------------+-------------+
|     1          | user_id     |
+----------------+-------------+
```

Tabela comentados:

```
+----------------+-------------+
| id_livro       | comentario  |
+----------------+-------------+
|     1          | coment 1    |
+----------------+-------------+
|     7          | coment 2    |
+----------------+-------------+
|     1          | coment 3    |
+----------------+-------------+
```

Tabela visitados:

```
+----------------+-------------+
| id_livro       | usuario     |
+----------------+-------------+
|     1          | user_id     |
+----------------+-------------+
|     6          | user_id     |
+----------------+-------------+
|     4          | user_id     |
+----------------+-------------+
```

No exemplo acima vemos que o livro com `id 1` se repete nas 3 tabelas e o livro com `id 4` se repete em duas delas, esses no caso seriam 2 livros que eu gostaria de recomendar para os clientes em uma lista pois aparentemente são dois livros "populares", como eu poderia organizar um `SELECT` que me retornasse os livros para que eu possa organizar eles na página "recomendados"

Comment: Qual critério você usaria pra mostrar os populares? Pelo diversidade de atividades? Pela quantidade de atividades? Ou limitaria por exemplo a 2 recomendações?

Comment: Se um livro se repete em pelo ao menos 2 tabelas ele é um bom livro para ser recomendado a diversidade de atividades relacionadas ao mesmo é um bom critério, seriam 3 livros para serem recomendados na página

Comment: Por que 3? No seu exemplo só vejo 2 atendendo o critério

Comment: Usei como exemplo só 2 que atendem as critérios para a pergunta não ficar muito extensa mas quero recomendar 3 livros que atendem os critérios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode adicionar 1 a uma coluna caso ache o registro em outra tabela e usar a soma dos 3 para ordenar os resultados:

```
SELECT l.id_livro,
       IFNULL((SELECT 1
                 FROM curtidos c
                WHERE c.id_livro = l.id_livro
                LIMIT 1), 0) as curtido, -- Coloca 1 se o livro foi curtido ou 0 se não foi
       IFNULL((SELECT 1
                 FROM comentados c
                WHERE c.id_livro = l.id_livro
                LIMIT 1), 0) as comentado, -- Coloca 1 se o livro foi comentado ou 0 se não foi
       IFNULL((SELECT 1
                 FROM visitados v
                WHERE v.id_livro = v.id_livro
                LIMIT 1), 0) as visitado -- Coloca 1 se o livro foi visitado ou 0 se não foi
  FROM livros l
HAVING (curtido + comentado + visitado) > 2 -- Verifica se aparece em pelo menos 2 tabelas
 ORDER BY (curtido + comentado + visitado) DESC -- Ordena pelos que aparecem em mais tabelas
 LIMIT 3 -- Limita em 3 o número de resultados
```

Comment: Eita um pouco completo mas consegui entender e aplicar ao meu real uso, funcionou perfeitamente bem. Só uma dúvida consultas desse tipo atrasam o carregamento da página ou não fazem diferença?

Comment: Dependendo da quantidade de registros pode ficar pesado sim. Mas com poucos registros não vai afetar

Comment: A tabela de livro vai ter aproximadamente 400 livros, já a de curtidos, comentários, e visitados vai depender da quantidade de usuários, mas tais logs serão limpos uma vez a cada 3 meses, mas vou testar o uso desse e vejo se influencia muito.

Comment: Sorack, se eu adicionar um ORDER BY nos SELECTS pela data, isso irá favorecer os livros mais recentes em tais tabelas, certo? Se não, como posso deixar essa pesquisa um pouco mais dinâmica, pois estou testando aqui e sempre tenho os mesmo 3 livros.

Comment: @LeoLetto, você pode usar o `ORDER BY` que foi indicado e após isso colocar o campo de data: `ORDER BY (curtido + comentado + visitado) DESC, data`

Comment: Quando faço isso a pesquisa não retorna resultados

Comment: @LeoLetto na realidade acho que você precisa abrir outra pergunta com as modificações que você necessita, pelos comentários vai ficar confuso e reabrir essa questão seria errado